# Multiple paired t-tests on multiple variables simultaneously using dplyr/tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume a data structure like this:

```
   ID testA_wave1 testA_wave2 testA_wave3 testB_wave1 testB_wave2 testB_wave3
1   1           3           2           3           6           5           3
2   2           4           4           4           3           6           6
3   3          10           2           1           4           4           4
4   4           5           3          12           2           7           4
5   5           5           3           9           2           4           2
6   6          10           0           2           6           6           5
7   7           6           8           4           6           8           3
8   8           1           5           4           5           6           0
9   9           3           2           7           8           4           4
10 10           4           9           5          11           8           8
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate a paired t-test for every test separately (in this case meaning testA and testB, but in real-life I have much more tests). I want to do it that way that I compare the first wave of a given test with every other subsequent wave of the same test (meaning testA_wave1 vs testA_wave2 and testA_wave1 vs testA_wave3 in the case of testA).

This way, I was able to achieve it:

```
df %>%
 gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
 mutate(wave_ID = paste0("wave", parse_number(variable)),
        variable = ifelse(grepl("testA", variable), "testA",
                     ifelse(grepl("testB", variable), "testB", NA_character_))) %>%
 group_by(wave_ID, variable) %>% 
 summarise(value = list(value)) %>% 
 spread(wave_ID, value) %>% 
 group_by(variable) %>% 
 mutate(p_value_w1w2 = t.test(unlist(wave1), unlist(wave2), paired = TRUE)$p.value,
        p_value_w1w3 = t.test(unlist(wave1), unlist(wave3), paired = TRUE)$p.value) %>%
 select(variable, matches("(p_value)"))

  variable p_value_w1w2 p_value_w1w3
  <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>
1 testA           0.664        0.921
2 testB           0.146        0.418
```

However, I would like to see different/more elegant solutions that give similar results. I'm looking mostly for `dplyr`/`tidyverse` solutions, but if there is a completely different way to achieve it, I'm not against it.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:20,
testA_wave1 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
testA_wave2 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
testA_wave3 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
testB_wave1 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
testB_wave2 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
testB_wave3 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0))
```

Comment: What about `testA_wave2` vs. `testA_wave3`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I'm interested only in the comparison of the first wave with all subsequent waves. Therefore, testA_wave2 vs. testA_wave3 is not needed.

Comment: this is more of a statistics question but relevant to programming - you are running a lot of paired t-tests so will you adjust for multiple comparisons? Is there a more efficient longitudinal analysis you could be doing?

Comment: @Mike I know what you mean, but in this case a correction is not needed.

Comment: In relation to @Mike 's comment (for anyone landing here who did not follow it): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/explain-the-xkcd-jelly-bean-comic-what-makes-it-funny

Comment: My approach is somewhat similar to the ones below. I wrote a blog post walking through pairwise operations in the tidyverse that may be useful: https://www.bryanshalloway.com/2020/06/03/tidy-2-way-column-combinations/ . You also might check-out the `widyr` package by David Robinson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 03/16/2022**

The tidyverse has evolved and so should this solution.

First I make a simplifying assumption: If we designed the experiment, then we know what the groups are and how many waves we followed them through. If we don't know, then we can extract this information from the column names. See at below.

```r
library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

tests <- c("A", "B")
waves <- 3

comparisons <-
  list(
    test = tests,
    first = 1,
    later = seq(2, waves)
  ) %>%
  cross_df()
comparisons
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   test  first later
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 A         1     2
#> 2 B         1     2
#> 3 A         1     3
#> 4 B         1     3
```

Transform the data from wide format to long format.

```r
data <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -ID,
    names_to = "test_wave"
  ) %>%
  extract(
    test_wave, c("test", "wave"),
    regex = "test(.+)_wave(.+)",
    convert = TRUE
  )
```

Then pair the comparisons we want to make with the data we collected. I've added lots of rename statements to make for more readable code but it's not strictly necessary.

```r
comparisons %>%
  inner_join(
    data,
    by = c("test", "first" = "wave")
  ) %>%
  rename(
    value.first = value
  ) %>%
  inner_join(
    data,
    by = c("test", "later" = "wave", "ID")
  ) %>%
  rename(
    value.later = value
  ) %>%
  group_by(
    test, first, later
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ tidy(t.test(.x$value.first, .x$value.later, paired = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = test,
    names_from = later,
    names_glue = "wave1_vs_wave{later}",
    values_from = p.value
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   test  wave1_vs_wave2 wave1_vs_wave3
#>   <chr>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A              0.664          0.921
#> 2 B              0.146          0.418
```

*Appendix*: Extract test names and number of waves from column names.

```
design <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("test")) %>%
  colnames() %>%
  str_match("test(.+)_wave(.+)")
tests <- unique(design[, 2])
waves <- max(as.integer(design[, 3]))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Old solution**

Here is one way to do it, using `purrr` quite a bit.

```r
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  ID = 1:20,
  testA_wave1 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
  testA_wave2 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
  testA_wave3 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
  testB_wave1 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
  testB_wave2 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0),
  testB_wave3 = round(rnorm(20, 5, 3), 0)
)

pvalues <- df %>%
  # From wide tibble to long tibble
  gather(test, value, -ID) %>%
  separate(test, c("test", "wave")) %>%
  # Not stricly necessary; will order the waves alphabetically instead
  mutate(wave = parse_number(wave)) %>%
  inner_join(., ., by = c("ID", "test")) %>%
  # If there are two waves w1 and w2,
  # we end up with pairs (w1, w1), (w1, w2), (w2, w1) and (w2, w2),
  # so filter out to keep the pairing (w1, w2) only
  filter(wave.x == 1, wave.x < wave.y) %>%
  nest(ID, value.x, value.y) %>%
  mutate(pvalue = data %>%
           # Perform the test
           map(~t.test(.$value.x, .$value.y, paired = TRUE)) %>%
           map(broom::tidy) %>%
           # Also not strictly necessary; you might want to keep all
           # information about the test: estimate, statistic, etc.
           map_dbl(pluck, "p.value"))
pvalues
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   test  wave.x wave.y data              pvalue
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <list>             <dbl>
#> 1 testA      1      2 <tibble [20 x 3]>  0.664
#> 2 testA      1      3 <tibble [20 x 3]>  0.921
#> 3 testB      1      2 <tibble [20 x 3]>  0.146
#> 4 testB      1      3 <tibble [20 x 3]>  0.418

pvalues %>%
  # Drop the data in order to pivot the table
  select(- data) %>%
  unite("waves", wave.x, wave.y, sep = ":") %>%
  spread(waves, pvalue)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   test  `1:2` `1:3`
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 testA 0.664 0.921
#> 2 testB 0.146 0.418
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however, it also gives a redundant comparison of wave2 vs wave3. I would like to avoid such a step.

Comment: @tmfmnk just add another filter condition: `wave.x == 1` should cover it... so `filter(wave.x < wave.y, wave.x == 1)`

Comment: Yes. Changed the filter condition to make a comparison between wave 1 and later waves.

Answer (score 11):

Since `dplyr` 0.8.0 we can use `group_split` to split a dataframe into list of dataframes.

We `gather` the dataframe and convert it into long format and then `separate` the names of the column (`key`) into different columns (`test` and `wave`). We then use `group_split` to split the dataframe into list based on `test` column. For every dataframe in the list we `spread` it into wide format and then calculate the `t.test` values and rbind them into one dataframe using `map_dfr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  separate(key, c("test", "wave")) %>%
  group_split(test) %>% #Previously we had to do split(.$test) here
  map_dfr(. %>%
          spread(wave, value) %>%
          summarise(test = first(test),
                    p_value_w1w2 = t.test(wave1, wave2, paired = TRUE)$p.value, 
                    p_value_w1w3 = t.test(wave1, wave3, paired = TRUE)$p.value))


# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  test  p_value_w1w2 p_value_w1w3
#  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 testA        0.664        0.921
#2 testB        0.146        0.418
```

We manually perform the t-test above as there were only 2 values which needed to be calculated. If there are more number of `wave...` columns then this could become cumbersome. In such cases we could do

```
df %>%
   gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
   separate(key, c("test", "wave")) %>%
   group_split(test) %>% 
   map_dfr(function(data) 
              data %>%
                   spread(wave, value) %>%
                   summarise_at(vars(setdiff(unique(data$wave), "wave1")), 
                   function(x) t.test(.$wave1, x, paired = TRUE)$p.value) %>%
                   mutate(test = first(data$test)))

#  wave2 wave3 test 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1 0.664 0.921 testA
#2 0.146 0.418 testB
```

Here it will perform the t-test for every "wave.." column with "wave1" column.

---

Since you are also open to other solutions, here is an attempt with purely base R solution

```
sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub("_.*", "", names(df[-1]))), function(x) 
 c(p_value_w1w2 = t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]],paired = TRUE)$p.value, 
   p_value_w1w3 = t.test(x[[1]], x[[3]],paired = TRUE)$p.value))


#                 testA     testB
#p_value_w1w2 0.6642769 0.1456059
#p_value_w1w3 0.9209554 0.4184603
```

We split the columns based on `test*` and create a list of dataframes and apply `t.test` on different combinations of columns for each dataframe.

Comment: Nice, learned something `group_split`. However, require quite some hard-coding of there should be than 2 waves per test.

Comment: @thothal you are right but since it was hard coded in OP's example, I thought they would have only 2 values to calculate but in any case it is good to have a scalable solution. Thank you, I have updated the answer which would work for many "wave" columns. :)

Answer (score 3):

To throw in a `data.table` solution:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) ## for the pipe operator

dt_sol <- function(df) {
  ## create patterns for the melt operation:
  ## all columns from the same wave should go in one column
  grps <- str_extract(names(df)[-1], 
                      "[0-9]+$") %>%
    unique() %>%
    paste0("wave", ., "$")
  grp_names <- sub("\\$", "", grps)
  ## melt the data table: all test*_wave_i data go into column wave_i
  df.m <- melt(df, 
               measure = patterns(grps),
               value.name = grp_names,
               variable.name = "test")
  ## define the names for the new column, we want to extract estimate and p.value
  new_cols <- c(outer(c("p.value", "estimate"), 
                      grp_names[-1],
                      paste, sep = "_"))
  ## use lapply on .SD which equals to all wave_i columns but the first one
  ## return estimate and p.value
  df.m[, 
       setNames(unlist(lapply(.SD, 
                              function(col) {
                                t.test(wave1, col, paired = TRUE)[c("p.value", "estimate")]
                              }), recursive = FALSE), new_cols),
       test, ## group by each test
       .SDcols = grp_names[-1]] 
}
dt <- copy(df)
setDT(dt)
dt_sol(dt)
#    test p.value_wave2 estimate_wave2 p.value_wave3 estimate_wave3
# 1:    1     0.6642769           0.40     0.9209554           -0.1
# 2:    2     0.1456059          -1.45     0.4184603            0.7
```

---

**Benchmark**

Comparing the `data.table` solution to the `tidyverse` solution we get an 3-fold speed increase with teh `data.table`solution:

```
dp_sol <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    gather(test, value, -ID) %>%
    separate(test, c("test", "wave")) %>%
    inner_join(., ., by = c("ID", "test")) %>%
    filter(wave.x == 1, wave.x < wave.y) %>%
    nest(ID, value.x, value.y) %>%
    mutate(pvalue = data %>%
             map(~t.test(.$value.x, .$value.y, paired = TRUE)) %>%
             map(broom::tidy) %>%
             map_dbl(pluck, "p.value"))
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(dplyr = dp_sol(df),
               data.table = dt_sol(dt))


# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#       dplyr 6.119273 6.897456 7.639569 7.348364 7.996607 14.938182   100   b
#  data.table 1.902547 2.307395 2.790910 2.758789 3.133091  4.923153   100  a
```

With a slightly bigger input:

```
make_df <- function(nr_tests = 2,
                    nr_waves = 3,
                    n_per_wave = 20) {
  mat <- cbind(seq(1, n_per_wave),
               matrix(round(rnorm(nr_tests * nr_waves * n_per_wave), 0),
                      nrow = n_per_wave))
  c_names <- c(outer(1:nr_waves, 1:nr_tests, function(w, t) glue::glue("test{t}_wave{w}")))
  colnames(mat) <- c("ID", c_names)
  as.data.frame(mat)
}

df2 <- make_df(100, 100, 10)
dt2 <- copy(df2)
setDT(dt2)

microbenchmark(dplyr = dp_sol(df2),
               data.table = dt_sol(dt2)

# Unit: seconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#       dplyr 3.469837 3.669819 3.877548 3.821475 3.984518 5.268596   100   b
#  data.table 1.018939 1.126244 1.193548 1.173175 1.252855 1.743075   100  a
```

Answer (score 3):

Using all combinations without replacement:

Just for `testA` group:

```
comb <- arrangements::combinations(names(df)[grep("testA",names(df))], k = 2,n =  3,replace = F )

tTest <- function(x, data = df){ 
  ttest <- t.test(x =data[x[1]] , y = data[x[2]])
  return(data.frame(var1 = x[1],
                    var2 = x[2],
                    t = ttest[["statistic"]][["t"]],
                    pvalue = ttest[["p.value"]]))
}

result <- apply(comb, 1, tTest, data = df)
```

Result:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(result)
         var1        var2          t    pvalue
1 testA_wave1 testA_wave2  0.5009236 0.6193176
2 testA_wave1 testA_wave3 -0.6426433 0.5243146
3 testA_wave2 testA_wave3 -1.1564854 0.2547069
```

For all groups:

```
comb <- arrangements::combinations(x = names(df)[-1], k = 2,n =  6, replace = F )
result <- apply(comb, 1, tTest, data = df)
```

Result:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(result)

         var1        var2          t    pvalue
1  testA_wave1 testA_wave2  0.5009236 0.6193176
2  testA_wave1 testA_wave3 -0.6426433 0.5243146
3  testA_wave1 testB_wave1  0.4199215 0.6769510
4  testA_wave1 testB_wave2 -0.3447992 0.7321465
5  testA_wave1 testB_wave3  0.0000000 1.0000000
6  testA_wave2 testA_wave3 -1.1564854 0.2547069
7  testA_wave2 testB_wave1 -0.1070172 0.9153442
8  testA_wave2 testB_wave2 -0.8516264 0.3997630
9  testA_wave2 testB_wave3 -0.5640491 0.5762010
10 testA_wave3 testB_wave1  1.1068781 0.2754186
11 testA_wave3 testB_wave2  0.2966237 0.7683692
12 testA_wave3 testB_wave3  0.7211103 0.4755291
13 testB_wave1 testB_wave2 -0.7874100 0.4360152
14 testB_wave1 testB_wave3 -0.4791735 0.6346043
15 testB_wave2 testB_wave3  0.3865414 0.7013933
```

Answer (score 1):

To throw another, somewhat more concise, `data.table` solution into the mix, in which we melt the data into long format:

```
setDT(df)
x = melt(df[,-1])[, tname := sub('_.+','',variable)][, wave := sub('.+_','',variable)]  

x[wave != 'wave1', .(p.value = 
   t.test(x[tname==test & wave == 'wave1', value], value, paired = TRUE)$p.value), 
  by = .(test=tname,wave)]
#     test  wave   p.value
# 1: testA wave2 0.6642769
# 2: testA wave3 0.9209554
# 3: testB wave2 0.1456059
# 4: testB wave3 0.4184603
```