# Multiple tests with pairwise combinations using dplyr/tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068779/multiple-paired-t-tests-on-multiple-variables-simultaneously-using-dplyr-tidyver) but a more complex example, in which I would like to statistically compare multiple columns in all combinations, and each of the columns has a different number of samples.

Consider the original data:

```
# A tibble: 51 x 3
   trial person score
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 foo   a      0.266
 2 bar   b      0.372
 3 foo   c      0.573
 4 bar   a      0.908
 5 foo   b      0.202
 6 bar   c      0.898
 7 foo   a      0.945
 8 bar   b      0.661
 9 foo   c      0.629
10 foo   b      0.206
```

For each trial type, I'd like to run a statistical test comparing the scores of each person. So, I need the following test results:

- Trial `foo`, compare all `score` samples of persons A–B, B–C, C–A
- Trial `bar`, compare all `score` samples of persons A–B, B–C, C–A

Of course, there are more than two trials, and more than three persons.

Hence, the solution using `group_split` given in the other question does not work, as it implies always testing agains the first person (in my case), not all pairwise combinations.

So, in the following code, I'm stuck at two points:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
library(broom)

set.seed(1)

df = tibble::tibble(
    trial = rep(c("foo", "bar"), 30),
    person = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 20),
    score = runif(60)
  ) %>% 
  filter(score > 0.2)

df %>% 
  group_by(person, trial) %>% 
  summarize(scores = list(score)) %>% 
  spread(person, scores) %>%
  group_split(trial) %>% 
  map_df(function(data) {
    data %>% 
      summarize_at(vars(b:c), function(x) {
        wilcox.test(.$a, x, paired = FALSE) %>% broom::tidy
      })
  })
#> Error in wilcox.test.default(.$a, x, paired = FALSE): 'x' must be numeric
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The value of `x` is apparently not just the actual list of scores, but the column vector of scores for a single trial. But I don't know how else to deal with the fact that the number of samples in each person is different.

Also, I still have to manually specify the column names, which would already be a combinatorial nightmare if there were more than, say, four persons.

I can somehow get the combinations as such:

```r
df %>% 
  group_split(trial) %>% 
  map_df(function(data) {
    combinations = expand(tibble(x = unique(data$person), y = unique(data$person)), x, y) %>% filter(x != y)
  })
```

… but that doesn't really help in creating columns for comparison.

What could I do to make this work?

Comment: In before someone mentions that a lot of statistical pairwise comparisons require alpha-correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to programmatically specify combinations and get around the error you were hitting in `wilcox.test()`.

```
combos <- unique(df$person) %>%
  combn(2, simplify = F) %>%
  set_names(map_chr(., ~ paste(., collapse = "_")))

df %>% 
  group_split(trial) %>%
  set_names(map_chr(., ~ unique(.$trial))) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    map_df(combos, function(y) {
      filter(x, person %in% y) %>% 
        wilcox.test(score ~ person, data = .) %>% 
        broom::tidy()
    }, .id = "contrast")
  }, .id = "trial")

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  trial contrast statistic p.value method                 alternative
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>      
1 bar   a_b             34   0.878 Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided  
2 bar   a_c             32   1     Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided  
3 bar   b_c             31   0.959 Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided  
4 foo   a_b             41   1     Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided  
5 foo   a_c             41   1     Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided  
6 foo   b_c             43   0.863 Wilcoxon rank sum test two.sided
```

Since this differs a lot from the pattern you started with, I'm not sure it will work for your real world case, but it works here so I wanted to share.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I have to adapt it to my real world case, as you mentioned. In my case, I might need more than one group, so there could be, say, `group_split(trial, region)`. How would I then set the names of the split data frames?

Comment: Hmm, I see there's a [workaround here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4223#issuecomment-469269857).

Comment: I would use `unite()` to build the unique grouping variable before you head into `group_split()` then use `separate()` when the testing is done to split back into the original variables

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution that uses nesting to handle groups (persons) with different number of measurements.

```r
library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1)

df <-
  tibble(
    trial = rep(c("foo", "bar"), 30),
    person = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 20),
    score = runif(60)
  ) %>%
  filter(score > 0.2)

comparisons <- df %>%
  expand(
    trial,
    group1 = person,
    group2 = person
  ) %>%
  filter(
    group1 < group2
  )
comparisons
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   trial group1 group2
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 bar   a      b     
#> 2 bar   a      c     
#> 3 bar   b      c     
#> 4 foo   a      b     
#> 5 foo   a      c     
#> 6 foo   b      c

df <- df %>% nest_by(trial, person)
df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Rowwise:  trial, person
#>   trial person               data
#>   <chr> <chr>  <list<tibble[,1]>>
#> 1 bar   a                 [8 × 1]
#> 2 bar   b                 [8 × 1]
#> 3 bar   c                 [8 × 1]
#> 4 foo   a                 [9 × 1]
#> 5 foo   b                 [9 × 1]
#> 6 foo   c                 [9 × 1]

comparisons %>%
  inner_join(
    df, by = c("trial", "group1" = "person")
  ) %>%
  inner_join(
    df, by = c("trial", "group2" = "person")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    p.value = map2_dbl(
      data.x, data.y, ~ wilcox.test(.x$score, .y$score)$p.value
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   trial group1 group2             data.x             data.y p.value
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <list<tibble[,1]>> <list<tibble[,1]>>   <dbl>
#> 1 bar   a      b                 [8 × 1]            [8 × 1]   0.878
#> 2 bar   a      c                 [8 × 1]            [8 × 1]   1    
#> 3 bar   b      c                 [8 × 1]            [8 × 1]   0.959
#> 4 foo   a      b                 [9 × 1]            [9 × 1]   1    
#> 5 foo   a      c                 [9 × 1]            [9 × 1]   1    
#> 6 foo   b      c                 [9 × 1]            [9 × 1]   0.863
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>