# Nest or group a dataframe, perform t tests (t.test) between all comparisons and return the p values

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse

Let's say I have a data frame in which the grouped variable is `quest`. I would like to nest my df using this variable and then perform a t.test for all possible comparisons and get the p values. The closest approach that I found is this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068779/multiple-paired-t-tests-on-multiple-variables-simultaneously-using-dplyr-tidyver)

The long way should be as follows

```
df <- data.frame(quest = c("2","4","6"), 
                 item_1 = rnorm(12,5,1),
                 item_2 = rnorm(12,5,1),
                 item_3 = rnorm(12,5,1))
df %>% 
  filter(quest == 2) %>%
  summarise(p=t.test(item_1, item_2, paired=T)$p.value)

df %>% 
  filter(quest == 2) %>%
  summarise(p=t.test(item_1, item_3, paired=T)$p.value)


df %>% 
  filter(quest == 2) %>%
  summarise(p=t.test(item_2, item_3, paired=T)$p.value)
```

After this, I'll have to use `quest==6`
.

I have a gut felling that `nest` will resolve this issues. Something like that:

```
df %>% 
  nest_by(quest) %>% 
  all t tests here, with p values %>% 
  unnest()
```

-I would like to use all tidyverse functions.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `combn` for pairwise combination

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    nest_by(quest) %>% 
    summarise(categ = combn(names(data), 2, paste, collapse="_"), 
       pval = combn(data, 2, function(x) 
          t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]], paired = TRUE)$p.value), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  quest categ          pval
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 2     item_1_item_2 0.581
2 2     item_1_item_3 0.416
3 2     item_2_item_3 0.263
4 4     item_1_item_2 0.886
5 4     item_1_item_3 0.101
6 4     item_2_item_3 0.106
7 6     item_1_item_2 0.426
8 6     item_1_item_3 0.983
9 6     item_2_item_3 0.362
```

---

Or reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and use `pairwise.t.test`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -quest) %>%
   group_by(quest) %>% 
   summarise(pout = list(broom::tidy(pairwise.t.test(value, name, 
        p.adjust.method = "none", paired = TRUE)))) %>% 
   unnest(pout)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  quest group1 group2 p.value
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1 2     item_2 item_1   0.581
2 2     item_3 item_1   0.416
3 2     item_3 item_2   0.263
4 4     item_2 item_1   0.886
5 4     item_3 item_1   0.101
6 4     item_3 item_2   0.106
7 6     item_2 item_1   0.426
8 6     item_3 item_1   0.983
9 6     item_3 item_2   0.362
```

NOTE: here we used the `p.adjust.method` as "none" to match the `combn` output.

Comment: Thanks a lot (again!). That's the first time I see the  `combn` function.

Comment: in the original dataset, if I have exactly the same means/ variances, the pairwise.t.test doesn't work.  Do you know how to fix it ?
`df <- data.frame(quest = c("2","4","6"), 
                 item_1 = rnorm(12,5,1),
                 item_2 = rnorm(12,5,1),
                 item_3 = rnorm(12,5,1)) 

df <- df %>% mutate(item_1=item_3)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -quest) %>%
  group_by(quest) %>% 
  summarise(pout = list(broom::tidy(pairwise.t.test(value, name, 
                                           p.adjust.method = "none", paired = TRUE)))) %>% 
  unnest(pout)`

Comment: @Luis It returns NA for those cases and is dropped while `tidy`ing.  What is your expected for those?

Comment: @Luis you may check `df   %>%   mutate(item_1=item_3) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -quest) %>%   group_by(quest) %>%    summarise(pout = list(reshape2::melt(pairwise.t.test(value, name,                                             p.adjust.method = "none", paired = TRUE)$p.value))) %>% unnest(pout)`

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much !!!